# How to convert a decimal field (13.2) to char in power center

Tags: informatica-powercenter

How to convert a decimal field (13.2) to char in power center, i have this value in other table 243.00 but the value that return is this 243, i need the follow value 243.00, pls your help

TO_CHAR(field)

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way. Here is a trick you can apply -
`SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(col_name+.001),1, length(TO_CHAR(col_name)) )`
Please validate it before applying.